# Which GeoTIFF tags tell me what I want to know?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, library

I'm reading some GeoTIFF files into my app using `libgeotiff`. After the model of the `listgeo` program that comes with libgeotiff, I want to extract the extents (corners) of the GeoTIFF so I can position it.

I only really want to deal with coords in WGS84 and UTM (ultimately, I'll convert WGS84 to UTM). However, I don't know which bit of the GeoTIFF info tells me what I want to know about the 'corner' coords. Obviously, I can use the magnitude of the numbers to guess if the resulting coords are lats and longs, but surely there must be an official way?

Something like (pseudo-code):

```
If (geotifftag == UTM || geotifftag == WGS84)
    // Proceed
Else
    Msg("Unrecognised data format")
End If
```

Could anybody help me out with what the GeoTIFF tags actually tell me?

Comment: Looks like you asked the same question (in a slightly more advanced way) again.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is through the GDAL API - see the [tutorial](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_tutorial.html) - your question then comes down to:

```
if( poDataset->GetProjectionRef()  != NULL )
    printf( "Projection is `%s'\n", poDataset->GetProjectionRef() );

if( poDataset->GetGeoTransform( adfGeoTransform ) == CE_None )
{
    printf( "Origin = (%.6f,%.6f)\n",
            adfGeoTransform[0], adfGeoTransform[3] );

    printf( "Pixel Size = (%.6f,%.6f)\n",
            adfGeoTransform[1], adfGeoTransform[5] );
}
```

and there is no difficulty reprojecting the corners to WGS84 if it is in a different projection.

Comment: GDAL is a comparatively heavyweight alternative. I tried it, but I'm left with the same problem. I'm not sure what 'projection' my corners are using. _"There is no difficult reprojecting the corners"_ - well, no difficulty if youknow how to do that and/or can penetrate the feeble GDAL documentation (I can't!)